# python subprocess.run("npx prettier --write test.ts", shell=True) does not work but running "npx prettier --write test.ts" in terminal does not

Tags: python, typescript, subprocess, prettier, npx

My file structure:

- test.py
- test.ts

and I am attempting to format the TypeScript file using a Python script. (Running this on Command prompt in Windows) However, when I run
my python file with `subprocess.run("npx prettier --write test.ts", shell=True)` shows

```
npm WARN config global '--global', '--local' are deprecated. Use '--location=global' instead.
test2.ts 136ms
```

as the output in the terminal but the ts file is not changed.

However, running `npx prettier --write test.ts` in the terminal has the same output but the ts file is correctly formatted using Prettier.

Does anyone know why this is the case and how to make the prettier formatting working using python subprocess?

Comment: We'd need a [mre], but some things to check: What's the current working directory in each case? Does `['npx', 'prettier', '--write', 'test.ts']` with `shell=False` behave the same way? In the interactive shell, does `type npx` (if that interactive shell is bash) tell you that there's a shell function, alias, or other thing that's changing how `npx` is implemented?

Comment: Also, which operating system is this? If it's a Linux distro where `/bin/sh` is dash or ash, that rules out some things that would be possible if it's bash (where exported functions could be overriding `npx` behavior from the parent process). The `shell=False` check should also rule those things out, though.

Comment: `shell=False` fails with `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: I am running this on Windows OS

Comment: Interesting. Make sure your `PATH` contains the directory that provides `npx` -- but beyond that, I'm going to need to let someone who knows Windows take over this one.

Comment: It should be, since running `npx prettier --write test2.ts` directly in cmd prompt works

Comment: This is where not knowing Windows shells puts me at a serious disadvantage -- but in UNIX shells, there are several alternate ways to define a command (aliases, shell functions, &c) besides an executable in the PATH.

Comment: That said -- when this happens, are you starting the Python interpreter _from your shell_, or are you starting it from a tool like an IDE? If the latter, does it still happen when Python was started from the same shell and terminal where the command otherwise succeeds?

Comment: Was able to solve it on my own after you mentioned looking at the reporducible example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with

```
with open("test.ts", 'w') as file:
   *** some changes ***
   subprocess.run("npx prettier --write test.ts", shell=True)
```

Putting the `subprocess.run` outside of the write works. I do not know the exact reason but I think it failed due to not being able to format/write the file itself within the open file resource that was opened with `with open()`.

Comment: There are two parts of this problem, and one of them is Windows-specific. The Windows-specific part is that a file opened for write by one process can't be opened for read by another. (I've seen Windows developers try to rely on this behavior for file locking, and then having their code fail badly when it's run on a non-Windows platform, so it's important to remember that that's Windows-specific behavior).

Comment: The part that _isn't_ Windows-specific is that if you haven't run `file.flush()` or `file.close()` -- and the latter is done automatically when you leave the `with` block -- the content from in the `*** some changes ***` section may not have been written out to disk yet due to IO buffering.